# 404 for certain .csv links in Yahoo Finance

Tags: http, yahoo, yahoo-finance

For example, http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?g=d&ignore=.csv&e=14&d=00&f=2016&b=2&a=1&c=2013&s=SAN.PA returns 404 to my server or HTTP checkers (even with user agent set to my browser).

But if I try this in my browser, I get 200 and it starts downloading the .csv.

Meanwhile, for most of the assets it works perfectly.

Should I use proxy, try some sophisticated user agent or even download the .csv client side?

Edit: http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com has the same behaviour.