# Yahoo Finance: 404 response code (PHP)

Tags: php, csv, fopen, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I'm using PHP to grab CSV files from Yahoo Finance based on an array of stock tickers.

My code is simple and is as follows:

```
$file = 'http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s='.$this->symbol.'&a='.$a.'&b='.$b.'&c='.$c.'&d='.$d.'&e='.$e.'&f='.$f.'&g='.$g.'&q=q&y=0&z='.$this->symbol.'&x=.csv';
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
//Then use fgetcsv to grab data, 
fclose($handle);
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Warning: fopen(http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=ANA.L&a=2&b=16&c=2016&d=2&e=19&f=2016&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=ANA.L&x=.csv): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found in y.php on line x

Manually entering the previous URL (http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=ANA.L&a=2&b=16&c=2016&d=2&e=19&f=2016&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=ANA.L&x=.csv) gets the CSV file with no problem, so I'm confused as to why I'm getting a 404 response code.

EDIT:
I have added a cURL request prior to using fopen. This is to check for a 404 response code. I am not getting any 404 response codes from the cURL but still getting the same error as mentioned above.

```
$curlhandle = curl_init($file);
curl_setopt($curlhandle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
/* Get the HTML or whatever is linked in $url. */
$response = curl_exec($curlhandle);
/* Check for 404 (file not found). */
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($curlhandle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if($httpCode == 404) {
    echo "404:".$this->symbol."<br>";
    curl_close($curlhandle);
    return null;
    break;
} else {
    curl_close($curlhandle);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");                        
}
```

Comment: When using the given URL as string (directly) to open the file via PHP, I do not receive any errors. Try to escape and encode your variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to URL encode all of your params otherwise you can have an invalid URL...

```
$file = 'http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s='.urlencode($this->symbol).'&a='.urlencode($a).' //etc
```

Comment: Added the`urlencode()` and I get exactly the same results

Comment: I don't see any parameters in there that need to be URL encoded. I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `ichart.yahoo.com` to `ichart.finance.yahoo.com`. i.e.

```
file = 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s='.$this->symbol.'&a='.$a.'&b='.$b.'&c='.$c.'&d='.$d.'&e='.$e.'&f='.$f.'&g='.$g.'&q=q&y=0&z='.$this->symbol.'&x=.csv';
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
//Then use fgetcsv to grab data, 
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Still get exactly the same results

Comment: @Calum This is quite weird. At first I was able to replicate the 404, but now I am not getting it for either URL.

Comment: Do you think it is something Yahoo side? Possibly throttling IPs?

Comment: @Calum I'm not sure. If that was the case I would have expected to not be getting 404s first and then started getting them later. It looks like you're also not the first person to experience this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786030/404-for-certain-csv-links-in-yahoo-finance

Comment: @Calum Lol, I just noticed you also found that a minute before me.

Comment: Very peculiar. I have an array of stock tickers and I seem to be receiving the  error randomly (i.e. not the same stock ticker each time).

Comment: @Calum I just tried again on a different server with a different IP address and the exact same thing happened. The first request I got a 404 and future requests worked fine. Does it work for you if you suppress the first 404 and then try the same request again?

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Calum `$file = 'http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s='.$this->symbol.'&a='.$a.'&b='.$b.'&c='.$c.'&d='.$d.'&e='.$e.'&f='.$f.'&g='.$g.'&q=q&y=0&z='.$this->symbol.'&x=.csv'; $handle = @fopen($file, "r"); @fclose($handle);` then put your existing code.

Comment: @Calum Put that before your existing code you have posted. It will suppress the error the first time you access the file but your existing code will show the error if you get it again the second time.

Comment: Sadly getting the same problem!